# Parse Style from HTML element background missing

Tags: html, css, vba

I am completely stumped. I'm parsing the HTML of a google images search using VBA's Internet explorer object. When I inspect the element with Chrome's built in tool, I get the HTML as something like this:

```
<a href="/imgres?imgurl=...&amp;imgrefurl=...&amp;docid=...&amp;tbnid=...&amp;vet=...&amp;w=1366&amp;h=768&amp;bih=638&amp;biw=1366&amp;q=cats&amp;ved=...;iact=mrc&amp;uact=8" jsaction="fire.ivg_o;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" rel="noopener" style="background: rgb(200, 190, 194); width: 270px; height: 168px; left: 0px;"><img class="rg_ic rg_i" data-sz="f" name="z7O-qKoPKHzyaM:" alt="Image result for cat's" jsaction="load:str.tbn" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ..." style="width: 300px; height: 168px; margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px; margin-top: 0px;"><div class="_aOd rg_ilm"><div class="rg_ilmbg"><span class="rg_ilmn"> 1366&nbsp;×&nbsp;768 - wallpapercave.com </span></div></div></a>
```

Or as a picture (Sorry, not sure how to format)

[image: HTML image]

There's a "background" value within the style set and I'd like to get this. However I can't seem to find it anywhere. When I go through the Properties with Chrome's inspection tool, there's no "Style" option available to look at. The `InnerHTML` does not contains some of the Style elements, but not "background".
And going through VBA

```
HTMLelement.getAttribute("Background") = ""
HTMLelement.Style.Background = ""
HTMLelement.Style.BackgroundColor = ""
```

What's going on, why can I see a background property when using the webpage inspector, but not access it through the above means?

Comment: @GustafGunér No JS being used, this is a VBA application (which I'm guessing uses some methods universal to object orientated languages). As a summary, I navigate an `InternetExplorer.Application` called `objIE` to a google images page, wait for it to load, then: `Set elem = objIE.document.getElementById("rg_s").getElementsByTagName("IMG")(0).ParentElement` where `elem` is the `IHTMLElement` I refer to in my question (I spread it out over more lines, but that's the idea)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose the `getAttribute("style")` method of the target `anchor` element can be used. Then the `style` is of type `IHTMLStyle` which has string property for *background* color. HTH

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Const url As String = "your-url-here"

Sub GetInlineStyle()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Debug.Assert Trim(url) <> ""
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = ie.document

    ' Get target anchor element which contains the background color
    Dim anchor As HTMLAnchorElement
    Set anchor = doc.querySelector("a[class=rg_l]")

    ' Use getAttribute("style") to get style of anchor
    Dim style As IHTMLStyle
    Set style = anchor.getAttribute("style")

    ' IHTMLStyle has string property backgroundColor
    Dim bgrColor As String
    bgrColor = style.backgroundColor
    Debug.Print bgrColor

    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

> Output

```
rgb(200, 190, 194)
```

> HTML used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Stackoverflow Greedo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="rg_l" rel="noopener" 
            style="background: rgb(200, 190, 194); width: 270px; height: 168px; left: 0px">
            Stackoverflow Greedo    
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, returning "" for the `style.backgroundColor` when using [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stack+overflow&tbm=isch) images search - even though `anchor` does point to the correct element on the page. I have used the IE inspector instead of the Chrome one, and have found no trace of the `background` property. This leads to 2 guesses; first that this property is unique to chrome, second that some ajax script removes the property in IE once the images are loaded. I may have to use Selenium unless you can think of how to get the data in IE?

Comment: @Greedo well now with the link provided I can fully undestand your problem :). But as you wrote, in IE there is no such inline style present. So the result of the `style.backgroundColor` is correct, I can't do anything with it :(.